# Let $R,S \subseteq A \times A$ be transitive binary relations. If $R\circ S=S\circ R$ then $R\circ S$ is also transitive.

Tags: combinatorics

My attempt to prove is the following:

Suppose $(x,a) \in R$ and $(a,y) \in S$, since $R\circ S=S\circ R$ then $(a,y) \in R$ and $(x,­a) \in S$.

Suppose $(y,b) \in R$ and $(b,z) \in S$, since $(a,y) \in R$ and $(y,b) \in R$ and $R$ is transitive then $(a,b) \in R$, once again because $R$ is transitive and $(x,a) \in R$ and $(a,b) \in R$ then $(x,b) \in R$.

Since $(x,b) \in R$ and $(b,z) \in S$ then $(x,z) \in R\circ S$ meaning it is transitive.

Is this answer correct?

Comment: Do not use squares and triangles for variable names.

Comment: No, it is not acceptable.  The first conclusion is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an algebraic proof, I present a point by point proof.
Assume aRoSb and bRoSc.
Thus exists x,y with aRx, xSb, bSy, yRc.
Since xSy:  aRoSy;  aSoRy.
Hence exists z with aSz, zRy.
Since zRc:  aSoRc;  aRoSc.